# create a list with default items

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio-2013

I know it's simple question, but it's new for me

I created a list in visual studio , I deployed the solution and worked fine. But I would like to add items in list as default from Visual studio, is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible.
When you create the list instance in Visual Studio, the created xml file contains the `<ListInstance>` element where you can add child `<Data>` element. That's where you can add the items to the list.
Here's the example xml definition which adds one item to the list:

```
<ListInstance
        Title="MyList"
        Description="MyList Description"
        FeatureId="xxx"
        Id="xxx"
        Url="Lists/MyList"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        QuickLaunchUrl="Lists/MyList/AllItems.aspx"
        RootWebOnly="FALSE"
        TemplateType="xxx" >
    <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Field1Name">test</Field>
          <Field Name="Field2Name">1</Field>
          <Field Name="Field3Name"><![CDATA[test]]></Field>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>
</ListInstance>
```

This [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms458199.aspx) contains the definition of the List Instance element and all the children that it can contain.